# Creating a trigger for Firebird database v2.5

Tags: triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to create a trigger for a firebird database, but have never done it before.

I want the trigger to fire when it leaves a record in a table JOBLINES. Is the trigger action "BEFORE UPDATE". The purpose of the trigger is to check a field has a value in it before being saved.

Do I want ACTIVE BEFORE?
How do I stop the database saving the new line if it doesn't meet the criteria?

What does position refer to in a trigger?
What if I want to use SQL to check the validity of the field entry?

I imagine "new." refers to a record that hasn't been saved yet. What if I want to check a line that has been edited?

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHECK_RELATED_JOB FOR JOBLINES
ACTIVE BEFORE 
  UPDATE
POSITION 0
AS
begin
    If new.AdditionalField_05 is null then 
          Showmessage('Assign Job for income');
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you might read the [Firebird trigger documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-triggers.html), which answers some of your questions. Close this question, and come back when you run into a specific problem.

Comment: I agree with pilcrow, first read the documentation, then ask a specific question. Currently your question is too broad, and the only real answer is "read the documentation". In addition to the link provided by pilcrow, make sure you read the [trigger DDL documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-trgr.html#fblangref25-ddl-trgr-create)

Comment: `The purpose of the trigger is to check a field has a value in it before being saved.` why would you even need a trigger for it ???????  Check `NOT NULL` clause at https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html  Then after that additionally read about SQL `CHECK CONSTRAINT`. You start with SQL data type (column, domain, etc) definition. If that is not enough - you make CHECK CONTRAINT. And only if both those approaches failed you only then start thinking about triggers.

Comment: If your sole purpose of making trigger is to provide custom error texts then look at the `SQL Exceptions`. but I would strongly suggest to separate concerns and to generate human-readable error texts in the client application not in the server itself. https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-handleexceptions.html